# How to reconnect app with Dropbox API

Tags: ios, swift, swiftydropbox

I have an iOS app written in Swift which downloads files from the Dropbox. For this purpose I'm using the SwiftyDropbox framework.

If I understand it right, the framework stores the generated access token in a shared memory so the app doesn't have to connect one more time.
My problem is that I want to clear this memory because I want to force my app to reauthorize.

The reason is that the app was bound via oauth1 which is not supported anymore. So I want to get a oauth2 token instead.
But I found no way. Removing and reinstalling the app has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`DropboxClientsManager.unlinkClients()`](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/) for this:

> call unlinkClients to logout Dropbox user and clear all access tokens